# zero padded integer with perl regex substitution

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I would like to do a zero padded integer with regex substitution.  I have for example the following string:

```
my $string = '3-7+9-15';
```

and want for output:

```
03-07+09-15
```

i know i could use sprintf, but i must first retrieve each integer do the sprintf and then re-join the integers into a string :(

i would like to do it in one pass with a regex substitution. is it possible ?

Comment: Why the down vote on this? It seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: @dawg: Presumably because the OP has shown no code and appears to have made no effort to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @borodin, as i said i have do some search since i have a solution with sprintf but wanted a one pass solution with regex...

Comment: @skualito: Yes, and you don't appear to have attempted to write a regex solution. I didn't vote your question down, I'm simply trying to answer **dawg's** comment.

Comment: `gradle :projects  | perl -pe 's{(.*)}{sprintf("gradle %-50s:dependencies \t\t\t--configuration compileClasspath", $1) ; }e'` if you have a huge git repo of gradle projects :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would choose to use `sprintf` in combination with a regex substitution

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = '3-7+9-15';
$s =~  s{(\d+)}{ sprintf '%02d', $1 }ge;
say $s;
```

#### output

```
03-07+09-15
```

Answer (score 4):

```
my $string = '3-7+9-15';
$string =~  s/\b(\d)\b/0$1/g;
say $string;
```

**Output:**

```
03-07+09-15
```

Comment: Or `s/\b(?=\d\b)/0/g`